# transitionTo not finding my ember route

Tags: ember.js, routes

Given the following route;

```
this.resource('show', { path: '/shows/:show_id' }, function() {
    this.resource('report', {path: '/reports/:report_id'}, function() {
        this.resource('interactions');
    });
});
```

I would have expected to be able to call;

```
transitionTo('show.report.interactions', show_model, report_model);
```

But I am getting a route not found error in my console.

I would be very grateful if someone could someone explain what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Protip: Use ember inspector which is a chrome plugin to check all of your application's routes.

Comment: @Hrishi I was using it and it looked like show.report.interactions should be a valid route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more digging (including looking in Ember Inspector, which was showing my original route as valid) I found that if you call `App.Router.router.recognizer.names` you can see all the routes that `transitionTo` can call.

Because interactions is a resource I could call it by itself and pass the models in, this will create the route I expected.

The final code then was just;

```
transitionTo('interactions', show_model, report_model);
```